# Is assigning an object with `null` creates a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory

I am assigning `null` value over a variable which holds a memory reference for an object. Does that action creates a memory leak?

```
var x = { a : 10 };
x = null;
```

So What I believe the above code would do is, after assinging the `x` with `null`, the reference that the x is holding would be replaced, but the value which was present in that replaced(older) memory reference will still be there. This sounds like a memory leak.

Can anyone confirm whether my assumption is correct or not? And also explain about how garbage collector in javascript behaves at this situation to flush the memory leak? Relevant links for the expiation would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no leak. Nothing is referring to `{a : 10}` any more once you set `x` to refer to something else.

So it's scheduled for garbage collection and the collector will collect it at leisure.